# While airflow initdb, ImportError: cannot import name HiveOperator

Tags: python-2.7, hive, airflow

I have recently installed `airflow` for my workflows. While creating my project, I executed following command:

```
airflow initdb
```

which returned following error:

```
[2016-08-15 11:17:00,314] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
DB: sqlite:////Users/mikhilraj/airflow/airflow.db
[2016-08-15 11:17:01,319] {db.py:222} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
ERROR [airflow.models.DagBag] Failed to import: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_twitter_dag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 247, in process_file
       m = imp.load_source(mod_name, file path)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_twitter_dag.py", line 26, in <module>
       from airflow.operators import BashOperator, HiveOperator, PythonOperator
ImportError: cannot import name HiveOperator
Done.
```

I checked some similar issues on web, which suggested me to install `airflow[hive]`, `pyhs2` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you using the `HiveOperator`? It seems like the error you are getting is due to 1 of the example dags. In production you should probably set `load_examples` to `False` and install `airflow[hive]` only if you are using the HiveOperator.

That being said, not sure why `airflow[hive]` isn't enough for you. You may try installing `airflow[hive,hdfs,jdbc]` but the airflow[hive] should be enough to get rid of the `HiveOperator` import error. Could you perhaps add what other error you are getting?

Comment: Seems like that is the issue. On production `airflow[hive]` worked for me. Can you tell me how to set `load_examples` to `False`.

Comment: Check out the `airflow.cfg` file. Airflow automatically creates the default `airflow.cfg` file for you in the AIRFLOW_HOME dir. The file has a variable `load_examples` which by default is set to `True`

Comment: The command `pip install airflow[hive]` was sufficient to resolve the error on a fresh install for me.

Comment: The tutorial triggers this problem.

Comment: I solved this by installing from the git repo: pip install -e "git+ssh://git@github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@master#egg=airflow"

Answer (score 3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 247, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_twitter_dag.py", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.operators import BashOperator, HiveOperator, PythonOperator
ImportError: cannot import name HiveOperator
```

If you still want to continue with installing sample data ... for Ubuntu 14.04 please use this method with python 2.7 the latest. (tested at DO )

> 1.apt-get update
>
> 2.apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
>
> 3.pip install --upgrade pip
>
> 3a.which pip #/usr/local/bin/pip
>
> 3b.pip -V #pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
>
> 4.pip install --upgrade virtualenv
>
> (Task 5 is optional)
>
> 5.apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/683601/how-to-upgrade-python-setuptools-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04
>
> 6.apt-get remove python-setuptools
>
> 7.pip install -U pip setuptools
>
> 8.export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
>
> 9.pip install airflow
>
> 10.pip install airflow[hive]
>
> 11.airflow initdb

You will get this response below

```
[2017-02-01 12:04:28,289] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-02-01 12:04:28,350] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2017-02-01 12:04:28,376] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
DB: sqlite:////root/airflow/airflow.db
[2017-02-01 12:04:28,522] {db.py:222} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Done.
```

**NOTE: Please Please apply necessary  sudo command if applicable**

Answer (score 0):

Check if the hive operator imported in the dag file?
If not,  You can do something like:

`from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator`